# why update doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I pass a json variable to a module but I can't do the update of my collection, always I have an error in the updating.

```
var gestion = function(myJSON) {
var dburl = 'localhost/mongoapp';
var collection = ['clientes'];
var db = require('mongojs').connect(dburl, collection );

        function cliente(nombre, estado, nuevo){
                this.nombre = nombre;
                this.estado = estado;
                this.nuevo = nuevo; 
        }

        var cliente1 = new cliente(myJSON.nombre myJSON.estado,  myJSON.nuevo);

if (cliente1.estado == "desconectado"){
                db.clientes.update(cliente1.nombre, {$set: {estado: "desconectado", nuevo: "no"}}, function(err) {
                        if (err) console.log("error "+cliente1.nombre);
                        else console.log("OK");
                        });
}

}           

return 0;
}
```

I also tried to remove my db and create one more time and I'm sure that my object exist in my db.

Comment: and what's the error message you are getting?

Comment: Error: selector must be a valid JavaScript object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature you should be using is

```
update(query, update, callback)
```

but you're passing a string for `query`, which doesn't mean anything to Mongo.  You may want to look at [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read/) for an overview, but for this specific instance, it looks like you're trying to find the document where `nombre` is equal to the string at `cliente1.nombre`.  The query for this is a dictionary `{ nombre: cliente1.nombre }`, so that line should be

```
db.clientes.update({nombre: cliente1.nombre}, {$set: {estado: "desconectado", nuevo: "no"}}, function(err) {
```